# How I can paginate custom array in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to paginate in view for a custom array. My controller and view code is given below.

Controller Code:

```
public function admin_detail(){
        $totalByDate = $this->Pbscodemetric->find('all',array('fields'=>array('created')));
        $createdDate = Set::extract('/Pbscodemetric/created', $totalByDate);
        $uniqueCreatedDate = array_unique($createdDate);
        $finalArray = array();
        foreach($uniqueCreatedDate as $created){
            $downloadsArr = $this->Pbscodemetric->find('all',array('fields'=>array('downloads_iphone','downloads_ipad','downloads_android'),'conditions'=>array('created'=>$created)));
            $download_iphone = array_sum(Set::extract('/Pbscodemetric/downloads_iphone',$downloadsArr));
            $download_ipad = array_sum(Set::extract('/Pbscodemetric/downloads_ipad',$downloadsArr));
            $downloads_android = array_sum(Set::extract('/Pbscodemetric/downloads_android',$downloadsArr));
            $finalArray[$created] = array(
                'downloads_iphone' => $download_iphone,
                'downloads_ipad' => $download_ipad,
                'downloads_android' => $downloads_android
            );
        }
        $this->set('finalArray',$finalArray);
    }
```

View Code:

```
<div class="pbscodemetrics index">
    <h2><?php echo __('Pbscodemetrics List Detail'); ?></h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>iPhone</th>
            <th>iPad</th>
            <th>Android</th>    
        </tr>
        <?php 
        foreach($finalArray as $key => $final){?>
            <tr> 
                <td><?php echo $key;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $final['downloads_iphone'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $final['downloads_ipad'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $final['downloads_android'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <?php echo $this->element('nav');?>
</div>
```

Now I want to set pagination. I know in CakePHP default pagination needs Model name. But How can I do that for the above code?

Can anyone help me please..

Comment: I assume Pbscodemetric.created is of type DATE, not DATETIME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom pagination, see [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) in the Cookbook. However, it looks like what you're doing there could be done using grouping and the SQL `SUM` function, that way you could then simply use the built-in pagination. Example:

```
$alias = $this->Pbscodemetric->alias;

$this->Pbscodemetric->virtualFields = array
(
    'downloads_iphone_sum' => sprintf('SUM(`%s.downloads_iphone`)', $alias),
    'downloads_ipad_sum' => sprintf('SUM(`%s.downloads_ipad`)', $alias),
    'downloads_android_sum' => sprintf('SUM(`%s.downloads_android`)', $alias)
);

$this->paginate = array
(
    'fields' => array
    (
        'downloads_iphone_sum',
        'downloads_ipad_sum',
        'downloads_android_sum',
        'created'
    ),
    'group' => 'created',
    'order' => array
    (
        'created' => 'desc'
    ),
    'limit' => 10
);

$data = $this->paginate($alias);
```

This will give you [Paginator helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html) compatible results with summed `downloads_iphone`, `downloads_ipad` and `downloads_android` columns, grouped by the `created` column. It uses virtual fields in order to retreive results in the default CakePHP style, ie they will be accessible like this:

```
    <?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $result['Pbscodemetric']['created'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['Pbscodemetric']['downloads_iphone_sum'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['Pbscodemetric']['downloads_ipad_sum'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['Pbscodemetric']['downloads_android_sum'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```